# Encrypting volumes of a mongo/elasticsearch cluster

Tags: amazon-web-services, mongodb, amazon-ebs, elasticsearch, disk-encryption

I have `mongodb` and `elasticsearch` cluster. I want to encrypt the volumes associated with all the instances running in the cluster. If I encrypt only one volume among the cluster than the cluster will be working normally? Or do I need to encrypt all the volumes in one go and run the cluster with all volumes encrypted?
What would be the best possible way to encrypt all volumes (specially having data)?

PS: I know the procedure of encrypting an existing volume.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a combination of encrypted and unencrypted volumes with the same instance.

To encrypt multiple volumes just do the same as a single volume multiple times. [Instructions here](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/EBSEncryption.html). Easiest way is probably to create an encrypted snapshot then create a new volume from that.